# How to set a list attribute to a node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This seems like a simple use case but I'm having trouble locating an example in the docs.

I want to do the following:

```
MERGE(node:Graph{id:{id}})
    ON CREATE SET node.firstseen = timestamp(),
    SET node.id = {id}, 
    node.list = [list]
```

Examples of this would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a comma before your `SET` clause:

```
    ON CREATE SET node.firstseen = timestamp(),
                                              ^
```

The correct query is

```
MERGE (node:Graph {id:$id})
ON CREATE SET node.firstseen = timestamp()
SET
node.list = $list
```

You don't need to set the `id` field, the `MERGE` takes care of this. The `list` field will be set every time you call the query, the `firstseen` timestamp only when the node doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks! you're absolutely right, i wanted to update as well as create but I left a comma there.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you pass `id` and `list` as [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/):

```
MERGE (node:Graph {id: $id})
ON CREATE SET
  node.firstseen = timestamp(),
  node.list = $list
```

You cannot have a `SET` clause within another `SET` clause. Besides, it is unnecessary to `SET node.id = $id` anyway, since your `MERGE` already guarantees that property has that value.

Comment: This is incorrect, supposedly the OP wants to update the list every time they call the query, not only on create.

Comment: This was not "incorrect". The question did not state that the list had to be set every time, and so could have been interpreted the way I did.